# Beamer: vertically center picture inside overlayarea

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is there an *easy*  way to vertically center a picture inside an `overlayarea` environment?

Here is a MWE of a small animation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.45\columnwidth}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\columnwidth}{.7\textheight}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=\columnwidth,height=.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]{picture1}
    \includegraphics<2>[width=\columnwidth,height=.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{picture2}
    \end{overlayarea}
\column{.45\columnwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Point A
    \item Point B
    \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Picture1 and picture2 will appear on the top of the columns, instead of being vertically centered (in fact, it is the `overlayarea` that is vertically centered, and all the picture inside are visibly aligned on its top)

The command `\vfill` does not seem to work.

Currently, I can correct the alignment of picture by inserting this kind of code:

```
\only<2>{\vspace{.25\textheight}}
```

But this requires manual adjustment...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility is to use a `\parbox` instead of `overlayarea`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.45\columnwidth}
\parbox[c][.7\textheight][c]{\columnwidth}{%
  \includegraphics<1>[width=\columnwidth,%
    height=.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]{image1}%
  \includegraphics<2>[width=\columnwidth,%
    height=.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{image2}%
}
\column{.45\columnwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Point A
    \item Point B
    \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Interesting. So, what is the purpose of the `overlayarea` environment if a `\parbox` seems to do the same (or even a better) job?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY quite frankly, I wouldn't know; in fact, `overlayarea` is defined using a `\vbox` of the given height  and then a `minipage` of the given width using `[t]` for the optional argument so, in a sense, it's more general to use a `minipage` or a `\parbox` from scratch.

Comment: `overlayarea` allows a lot more flexibility. eg: try `\alt` inside overlayarea.