# Vertically center when using overlayarea

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

Consider the following MWE:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}
      \begin{center}
        \input{big_tikz_image_with_many_overlays.tex}
      \end{center}
    \end{overlayarea}

    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.15\textheight}
      \begin{center}
        \only<8->{%
           Some text
        }
      \end{center}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
```

Here, the TikZ element in the upper part has several overlays, and the "Some text" should appear from slide `n` and on. In order to avoid "jumpy" slide I used the `overlayarea` environment. The problem is that when using this environment, the vertical centering of the content is broken. The two blocks are pushed towards the upper part of the frame. I tried to add `\vfill` between the two, but it didn't help.

How can I vertically center the content of the frame? Maybe, somehow enclose the two areas in a bigger box?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83672/beamer-vertically-center-picture-inside-overlayarea the given answer work very well for me

Comment: And if I use `overlayarea` after all? :)